# How to serialize and deserialize a Set attribute with Jackson and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization

I have two simple POJO models persisted with Hibernate and I am using Jackson to serialize and deserialize objects to JSON.

Here are my models TestCar and TestPart:

```java
public class TestCar
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = TestPart.class, mappedBy = "car", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TestPart> parts = new HashSet<>();
}

public class TestPart
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private TestCar car;
}
```

My Jackson initialization:

```java
Hibernate4Module h4m = new Hibernate4Module();
h4m.enable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);

mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(h4m);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

There is an issue with the `private Set<TestPart> pars` because it is serialized as `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet`:

```json
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Fiat",
    "parts" : [ "org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet", [ [ "com.acme.TestPart", {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "puerta"
      } ]
     ] ]
}
```

and when I try to deserialize it an error is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:155)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:160)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:308)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:116)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserializeWithType(CollectionDeserializer.java:320)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:497)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:101)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
```

Is there any way to serialize the hibernate PersistentSet as a simple Set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not using the ObjectMapper with the module installed. Perhaps you should reassign the mapper variable? Not sure to what extent ObjectMapper is mutable or a builder.

Comment: Hi Jan. I tried reassining the return value of regirsterModule but nothing changed. Any ideas ?

Comment: The JSON output should never be like yours. The JSON should look like a regular set or list (an array in JSON). You should not see anything related to "persistent set". Your JSON is now serialized without the plugin enabled (I know how the extension should behave) and you're trying to deserialize rubbish JSON.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point. So the issue is on the serialize process. I guess the Hibernate4Module is loaded because the feature FORCE_LAZY_LOADING is working. On the other hand, I instance the Hibernet4Module as it's documented on the project page on github. All of the examples I found use the same code as me.

Comment: Hi Jan, maybe there is a problem when you use an Entity with a Set or List attribute + Hibernate4Module + enableDefaultTyping(). If I disable the default typing setting the example works because the class name is not serialized but I really need it because I am serializing polymorphic objects.

Comment: Normally you would use `@JsonTypeInfo` for that: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html

Comment: It's a good idea Jan ! I tried removing `enableDefaultTyping()` and adding the `@JsonTypeInfo` and It seems to work fine. I found and issue when store models on Lists but it's explained here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336

Comment: Nice that you got it working now ^_^ that explains it then!

Comment: And yes type info only works on POJOs where the generic can be resolved, not on raw types. I am somewhere in that conversation as well (or probably created a duplicate issue)